# Creating list of Online users using SESSION without database?

Tags: php

I want to maintain a list of online users for my website WITHOUT database solution (so as to reduce the load).

Is it possible to achieve this with sessions?

Comment: You flag your Q as PHP5, so you have access to sqlite.

Yeah, this is a db, no you don't want to use a db, but sqlite is a file based db designed for this kind of work, why do you think it is worse than any other file operations?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the memcache for that. sessions and cookies both have the size limits which obviously is not the right choice

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can modify this class a little to also include the username:

[PHP Reports the number of users that are currently online](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/382-PHP-Reports-the-number-of-users-that-are-currently-online-.html)

Comment: thanks for the reply..But as my per requirement i only want name and id of the online users...

Comment: Ohh, I got the wrong idea from your question. You want to list all the users that are online (creating a list of names) to be displayed somewhere on your page.